# Data gets logged from one subscription in azure portal but not from an other subscription

Tags: azure, botframework

I have developed a bot using Microsoft bot framework.I need data for Application insights. I could log the data when testing in emulator in the Azure portal after executing the queries, but the same deployed in azure portal is not giving logs when I execute the same queries.One more thing i observed is data gets logged from other subscriptions in which i have developed bots.but the current subscription is not logging. Thnak you for your help.

Comment: What SDK are you using (NodeJS or .NET, V3 or V4)? And when you say "testing in emulator in the Azure portal" do you mean testing in Web Chat on the Azure Portal or testing locally in the Bot Emulator outside of Azure?